# Load mask for panel in ExtJS 3

Tags: mask, extjs3, masking

I want to add a loading mask for a specific item/panel. I do some research abaout this. In ExtJS 4 there is a function for all component which is `setLoading()`. Is there any equivalent for ExtJS 3?

I want do smt like this: http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/pKq8X/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});
myMask.show();
```

refer: http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/docs/
LoadMask

Comment: If put my panel instead of `Ext.getBody()` it gives error. I want block my panel not whole page.

Answer (score 6):

This may be too late for you, but after playing around with Rock123's suggestion I was able to get a loading mask with this code.

```
myPanel.getEl().mask("Please wait...","x-mask-loading");
```

And to unmask it

```
myPanel.getEl().unmask();
```

Answer (score 3):

if ur formpanel name is panel then ur code goes like this

```
panel.getForm().load({url:'dummyurl', waitMsg:'Loading'});
```

Refer the following for more clarification...

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/form/xml-form.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to make. But I don't use FormPanel and inside my panel there is a html code. I can't use `panel.getForm()` function and other functions.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of
Lookup an existing component by ID works fine for me

Ext.getCmp('**hr-graph-east**').getEl().mask("Please wait...","x-mask-loading");

Ext.getCmp('**hr-graph-east**').getEl().unmask();

```
            {xtype: 'hr_htmlpanel',
              id: 'hr-graph-east',
              height: 330,
              width: 500,
              etc..
```